# Flexible Function Declaration in Type Classes

Tags: haskell

I am trying to make a type class Expr, which represents a generic expression. An instance of this class is ExprT Supported expressions are literals, add, and multiply. Here is my code so far:

```
class Expr a where
    lit :: Eq x => x -> a
    add :: a -> a -> a
    mul :: a -> a -> a

data ExprT = Lit Integer
           | Add ExprT ExprT
           | Mul ExprT ExprT
  deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Expr ExprT where
    lit = Lit
    add = Add
    mul = Mul
```

However, when I run this, I get the following error:

```
* Couldn't match type `x' with `Integer'
      `x' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          lit :: forall x. Eq x => x -> ExprT
......
```

My goal is to make different instances of Expr for Integers, Floats, and maybe even non-numerical types like Chars, but I am not sure how to get past this error.

Comment: The signature `Eq x => x -> a` says that for *all* types `x`, this function will work, but `Lit` only accepts an `Integer`.

Comment: I understand, but is there any way to get past this? Is this the proper way to declare lit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well your signature for `lit` is very generic:

```
class Expr a where
    lit :: Eq x => x -> a
    add :: a -> a -> a
    mul :: a -> a -> a
```

Such signature says that your `lit` will accept any sort of type `x` for which `Eq x` holds. So for `ExprT`, one can pass an `Integer`, `Float`, `String`, etc. an you will return an `ExprT`. You probably do not want this.

You can define an extra parameter like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class Eq b => Expr a b | a -> b where
    lit :: b -> a
    add :: a -> a -> a
    mul :: a -> a -> a
```

and then declare an instance of `Expr` for `ExprT` as:

```
instance Expr ExprT Integer where
    lit = Lit
    add = Add
    mul = Mul
```

An alternative might be to "lift" your `ExprT` data type with a type parameter:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data ExprT a where
    Lit :: Eq a => a -> ExprT a
    Add :: ExprT x -> ExprT a -> ExprT a
    Mul :: ExprT x -> ExprT a -> ExprT a
```

and thus define this as:

```
class Expr e where
    lit :: Eq a => a -> e a
    add :: e a -> e a -> e a
    mul :: e a -> e a -> e a
```

```
instance Expr ExprT where
    lit = Lit
    add = Add
    mul = Mul
```